# Blackberry menu item problem

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to implement a menu item in my application.The code is here for BaseScreen Class

```
package com.kcrw.ui;


import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.FullScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;



public class BaseScreen extends MainScreen {

/*BaseScreen(){
super();
}*/
class NextQuesMenu extends MenuItem {

    public NextQuesMenu() {
        super("Live", 40, 10);
    }

    public void run() {

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new LiveScreen());
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());

        }
    }

protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
       menu.add(new NextQuesMenu());
       super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
    }

}
```

Now i am extending this class from LiveScreen class

```
package com.kcrw.ui;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;  
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;  
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;  
import com.kcrw.model.LiveStream;
import java.util.Vector;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.DrawStyle;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYRect;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Menu;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.FullScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import com.kcrw.model.LiveStream;
import com.kcrw.util.Constants;
import java.util.Vector;      

   public class LiveScreen extends BaseScreen {  

   private static final String NOT_FOUND = "Not Found";
    private static final String NEWS_CHANNEL = "NEWS CHANNEL";
    private static final String MUSIC_CHANNEL = "MUSIC CHANNEL";
    private static final String ON_AIR_NOW = "ON AIR NOW";
    public static LiveStream liveStream;
    public static LiveStream musicStream;
    public static LiveStream newsStream;
    public static DrawStyle topLive;
    public static DrawStyle bottomLive;
    MainScreen mainScreen; 
    /*switch (position) {
    case 0:
        if (liveStream.getProgram() == null)
            return;
        pid = "kcrwlive";
        url = liveStream.getProgram().getMobilePlayingImage()
                .getImageUrl();
        showUrl = liveStream.getProgram().getPageUrl();
        title = ON_AIR_NOW;
        desc = liveStream.getProgram().getDescription();
        if(bitRate==0) {
            audioUrl = Constants.liveAudioUrl_64k;
        } else {
            audioUrl = Constants.liveAudioUrl_128k;                     
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (musicStream.getProgram() == null)
            return;
        pid = "kcrwmusic";                  
        url = musicStream.getProgram().getMobilePlayingImage()
                .getImageUrl();
        showUrl = musicStream.getProgram().getPageUrl();
        title = MUSIC_CHANNEL;
        desc = musicStream.getProgram().getDescription();
        if(bitRate==0) {
            audioUrl = Constants.musicAudioUrl_64k;
        } else {
            audioUrl = Constants.musicAudioUrl_128k;                        
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (newsStream.getProgram() == null)
            return;
        pid = "kcrwnews";   
        url = newsStream.getProgram().getMobilePlayingImage()
                .getImageUrl();
        showUrl = newsStream.getProgram().getPageUrl();
        title = NEWS_CHANNEL;
        desc = newsStream.getProgram().getDescription();
        if(bitRate==0) {
            audioUrl = Constants.newsAudioUrl_64k;
        } else {
            audioUrl = Constants.newsAudioUrl_128k;                     
        }
        break;
    }

    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_ID, pid);
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_IMAGE_URL, url);
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_AUDIO_URL, audioUrl);
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_SHOW_URL, showUrl);                
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.ALBUM_DESCRIPTION, desc);
    intent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.IS_PROGRAM, true);

    LiveActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
});

}*/

    public LiveScreen(){  
   //super();
  HorizontalFieldManager _hfm;  

  //The _vfm will hold the ListField and we'll add it to the _hfm  
 VerticalFieldManager _vfm;  

//Create the vars for ListField creation  
final ListField myList;  
ListCallback myCallback;  


   //Get the device width and height  
     final int width = Display.getWidth();  
    final int height = Display.getHeight();



//Create the mainScreen - this holds the _hfm and _vfm managers  
//MainScreen mainScreen;  
 mainScreen = new MainScreen();  

     //Private class that we will create in a minute  
   myCallback = new ListCallback();  
    myCallback.erase();  

myList = new MyListField();  
 myList.setCallback(myCallback);  

 //Populate the list with sample elements  
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){  
      myList.insert(i);  
      myCallback.insert(ON_AIR_NOW , 0); 
      myCallback.insert(MUSIC_CHANNEL , 1);
      myCallback.insert(NEWS_CHANNEL , 2);

}  



 //Draw background gradient on this manager and add VerticalFieldManager for scrolling.  
    _hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager() {  

     public void paint(Graphics g)  
      {  


      //Variables for drawing the gradient  
     int[] X_PTS_MAIN = { 0, width, width, 0};   
       int[] Y_PTS_MAIN = { 0, 0, height, height };   
       int[] drawColors_MAIN = { Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.DARKBLUE, Color.DARKBLUE};  


      try {  
        //Draw the gradients     
          g.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS_MAIN, Y_PTS_MAIN, null, drawColors_MAIN, null);  

       } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {  
          System.out.println("Bad arguments.");   
       }  



       //Call super to paint the graphics on the inherited window   
       super.paint(g);  


      }  

    //Sublayout is passed the width and height of the parent window and will tell the window manager  
     //how to layout the buttons, images, etc.  
     protected void sublayout(int w, int h) {    

     //GetFieldCount returns the number of fields attached to the instance of this manager.  
    //and lays out the position  
             if (getFieldCount() >0) {                   

                    Field searchRes = getField(0);  
                   layoutChild(searchRes, width, height);  
                     setPositionChild(searchRes,0,0);  

               }  



              setExtent(width,height);  

        }  


  };  

   _vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT|Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {  

          /*public void paint(Graphics g)  
            {  
                 g.setColor(Color.GRAY);    
                super.paint(g);  

             }  

         protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time){  
                this.invalidate();  
                return super.navigationMovement(dx,dy,status,time);  
                }  */

       protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {



            layoutChild(myList, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            setPositionChild(myList, 5, 385);

            setExtent(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        }
        };  




             //Add the list to the verticalFieldManager  
              _vfm.add(myList);  

              //Add the verticalFieldManager to the HorizontalFieldManager  
             _hfm.add(_vfm);  
            //Finally, add the HorizontalFieldManager to the MainScreen and push it to the stack   
             mainScreen.add(_hfm);  
              //pushScreen(mainScreen);  
             UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(mainScreen);
                    //UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getActiveScreen());
                }
            });

       }//End Ctor  

 private class MyListField extends ListField{  


        //0,ListField.MULTI_SELECT  
         private boolean hasFocus = false;  

         public  void onFocus(int direction){  
           hasFocus = true;    
         }  

          public void onUnfocus()   
             {  
                    hasFocus = false;  
                     super.onUnfocus();  
                    invalidate();  
              }  

          public void paint(Graphics graphics)   
               {   int width = Display.getWidth();  
                    //Get the current clipping region   
                   XYRect redrawRect = graphics.getClippingRect();  
                    if(redrawRect.y < 0)  
                   {  
                      throw new IllegalStateException("Error with clipping rect.");  
                   }  

              //Determine the start location of the clipping region and end.  
                   int rowHeight = getRowHeight();  

                    int curSelected;  

                   //If the ListeField has focus determine the selected row.  
                   if (hasFocus)   
                 {  
                        curSelected = getSelectedIndex();  

                    }   
                  else   
                 {  
                  curSelected = -1;  
                 }  

                    int startLine = redrawRect.y / rowHeight;  
                    int endLine = (redrawRect.y + redrawRect.height - 1) / rowHeight;  
                   endLine = Math.min(endLine, getSize() - 1);  
                   int y = startLine * rowHeight;  

                    //Setup the data used for drawing.  
                   int[] yInds = new int[]{y, y, y + rowHeight, y + rowHeight};  
                    int[] xInds = new int[]{0, width, width, 0};  

                    //Set the callback - assuming String values.  
                  ListFieldCallback callBack = this.getCallback();  

                    //Draw each row  
                   for(; startLine <= endLine; ++startLine)   
                   {                 
                   //If the line we're drawing is the currentlySelected line then draw the fill path in LIGHTYELLOW and the   
                     //font text in Black.    
                 if(startLine == curSelected){  

                          graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHTYELLOW);  
                           graphics.drawFilledPath(xInds, yInds, null, null);  
                           graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
                          graphics.drawText((String)callBack.get(this, startLine), 0, yInds[0]);  

                   }  
                  else{  
                          //Draw the odd or selected rows.  
                         graphics.setColor(Color.LIGHTGREY);  
                          graphics.drawText((String)callBack.get(this, startLine), 0, yInds[0]);  
                   }  

                   //Assign new values to the y axis moving one row down.  
                      y += rowHeight;  
                      yInds[0] = y;  
                      yInds[1] = yInds[0];  
                      yInds[2] = y + rowHeight;  
                      yInds[3] = yInds[2];  
                    }  

                   //super.paint(graphics);  
               }  
       }  

  //Private class to populate the ListField private variable  
   private class ListCallback implements ListFieldCallback{  


    private Vector listElements = new Vector();  

       public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g,   
                           int index, int y, int w) {    

          String text = (String)listElements.elementAt(index);  
         g.setColor(Color.LIGHTGREY);  
          g.drawText(text, 0, y, 0, w);    
       }  

      public Object get(ListField list, int index) {    
         return listElements.elementAt(index);   
     }       

       public int indexOfList(ListField list, String p, int s) {    
          //return listElements.getSelectedIndex();  
         return listElements.indexOf(p, s);    
      }  


       public void insert(String toInsert, int index) {    
         listElements.insertElementAt(toInsert, index);    
       }  

      public void add(String toInsert){  
        listElements.addElement(toInsert);  
       }  

      public void erase() {    
          listElements.removeAllElements();    
       }  

   public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {  

     return 0;  
    }     
   }
   }
```

Then I am calling the LiveScreen(which displays listitems) class from SplashScreen & pushing the LiveScreen

But when I run the application, and when the control goes to LiveScreen. I click the menu, but the menu item is not shown.Can anyone guide me where I am making the mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you will find the following helpful, if your question isn't answered please feel free to respond and clarify your question.

When launching the menu option off the BaseScreen I would update the code so it includes a reference to the current screen instead of using getScreen().  This is because pushScreen method returns immediately and to me it looks like you've asked the code to push a screen onto the stack and then pop it off right away.

Here's what the BaseScreen change could look like:

```
    public void run() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new LiveScreen());
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(BaseScreen.this);
    }
```

On the live screen to see what the user selected you can use the navigatorClick method in the main screen.  The sample coded used an inline MainScreen (I would normally put this in its own class).

If you make the myList and myListCallback class variables or re-arrange the order they are created in the constructor, then you can augment the mainScreen instantiation to include a new navigationClick method which finds out what was clicked.

Here is what that could look like in LiveScreen:

```
    final ListField myList;
    final ListCallback myCallback;

    ...

    // MainScreen mainScreen;
    mainScreen = new MainScreen(){
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            int selected = myList.getSelectedIndex();
            if (selected != -1) {
                final Object o = myCallback.get(myList, selected);
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Status.show("Clicked on "+o);
                    }
                });
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are interacting with LiveScreen? Looks like the LiveScreen calls

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(mainScreen);
```

so my guess (guess because it's hard to read so poorly formatted code) you have a MainScreen on the top and that's why it does not hold your "Live" menu item.